# Setting highest resolution of 1920x1080 in my HDTV does not fill screen in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: display, intel-graphics, display-resolution, hdtv

I have a *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS* desktop with *Intel integrated graphics (Ivybridge)* which I have connected to my Android TV using a VGA to HDMI adaptor (VGA from desktop to HDMI in TV). I am using *Gnome flashback (metacity)* desktop as I have another issue with the Ubuntu desktop which is posted here - [Distorted graphics in Ubuntu 18.04 with intel integrated graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258012/distorted-graphics-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-intel-integrated-graphics). Ubuntu is unable to detect the highest resolution (1920x1080) automatically and these are the default modes listed by *xrandr*.

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have used *xrandr* to add the 1920x1080 mode and use it following the set of commands below

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1920x1080_60.00"

xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
```

The arguments to the newmode are generated using **"cvt"** utility. While the resolution appears to be okay, the aspect ratio does not seem to be 16:9 and the desktop does not fill the whole display as shown in the attached picture below.

[image]

I have tried changing the refresh rate to the specified values of the TV manufacturer but without any success. I have also tried the different fitting option (Full, Unscaled, Wide, 16:9 etc.) provided in the TV's picture setting menu, which also doesn't help. I couldn't find this kind of issue anywhere. I'll truly appreciate any help in this regard.

Many thanks.

Here are some of the system info:

```
$glxinfo -B
name of display: :1.0
display: :1  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop  (0x152)
    Version: 19.2.8
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 1536MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.2
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

```
$inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.8 ) drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@59.96hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Desktop version: 4.2 Mesa 19.2.8
```

```
$lshw -c video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: What does `$ xrandr` show as the default modes?

Comment: I have updated my post with the default modes listed by xrandr. Here are the same  ```$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)```

Comment: Well, after scratching my head for many days and trying out many things, finally I could get the full screen display. I learnt few things about Xorg and it's configuration files in this course. The trick was to generate the modeline using **cvt** with the reduced option as shown below -
```$ cvt -r 1920 1080```
The modeline generated using the above command has different parameters than those generated by only cvt. I can't explain why it worked. But I posted this solution in case if it helps others who have come across this kind of issue. Thanks to all.

Comment: I think I celebrated too early. Although the problem this morning is not so severe but still I found there are almost 10 pixel gaps on both the left and right side of the screen. I don't know why this happened.  I used this kernel parameter during boot to have a full HD virtual terminal and login screen ```video=VGA-1:1920x1080MR@60```.