# Visual Glitches on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, video, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

Since a couple of days ago I am experiencing huge visual glitches on my screen (only in some apps). The issue gets worse while in high CPU usage. I've tried to update the video driver, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

[image: Bug Screenshot]

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
```

Comment: Multiple similar issues reported nowadays. Could you try booting to an earlier kernel version to see if the issue persists then?

Comment: @vanadium Thank you for your suggestion, I will be trying this soon.

Comment: @vanadium I tried this:

`GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ioummu=pt"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

Unfortunately, it didn't work. Could you review my attempt and give me another feedback?

Comment: Are you on a laptop? That might be issues with the power saving features of Intel Graphics cards. Check whether the issues are also there on AC power. Indeed, if that is the issue, it would be possible to disable power saving using kernel parameters.

Comment: @vanadium Yes, I am using a laptop and the issues are there with or without AC power on. Assuming I did it correctly, it didn't solve the problem, even though both attempts apparently reduced the behavior. 

`GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet iommu=pt i915.enable_psr=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

Comment: For me it works adding `i915.enable_psr=0` (I did not need it anymore, but now with 21.04 graphical issues are back, and this helped). Make sure to run  `sudo update-grub` after changing `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distorted graphics in Ubuntu 18.04 with intel integrated graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258012/distorted-graphics-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-intel-integrated-graphics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been two days without any distortion or glitch on my screen, so I think it is reasonable to say that the problems were solved.

Time to share with the community what I did to get it fixed.

First, the solutions @vanadium suggested decreased the distortions somehow.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0 GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet iommu=pt i915.enable_psr=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

But [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258012/distorted-graphics-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-intel-integrated-graphics) solved the problem, I created a /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf file with touch command and inserted these configs:

```
    Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
   Option      "DRI"         "1"
    EndSection
```